# Angular MatDrawerMode has no exported member 'MatDrawerMode'

Tags: angular, angular-material, drawer

I get `TS2305: Module '"../../../../node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav"' has no exported member 'MatDrawerMode'.` an error while using the MatDrawerMode here is my code

at the component:

```
import { MatDrawerMode } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

// used as a property 
sidebarMode: MatDrawerMode;
```

app.modules

```
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';

...
  imports: [
    MatSidenavModule,
...
```

I've tried to delete @angular from node_modules, and also the complete node_modules.

What am I missing out?

Answer (score 0):

use 'MatSidenav' at component level instead  MatDrawerMode

```
   import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that I was still on angular material 8, so I had to move to 9 in my package.json

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/material": "~9.2.4",
// ...
```

and it works now